# Extension of Array in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

How would a simple function like `index(of:)` be implemented in a swift 3 extension. Please provide an example with the practices required to implement the example are.

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/CollectionAlgorithms.swift.gyb: `public func index(of element: ${IElement}) -> Index?`

Comment: Clone the source code (instructions at https://github.com/apple/swift) and then use your favourite tool (e.g. "grep -r") to find what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the syntax of an extension of Array in Swift 3 here it is

```
extension Array {
    func foo() { }
}
```

You can also restrict the extension to be available only where the Element of the array does conform to some protocol

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    func foo() { }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for an example of this syntax in practice such as the implementation of `index(of:)` possible with an explanation of what to lookout for when writing extensions related to the example. Martin R provided an example, but I would appreciate a explanation of the practices that go into making it as well.

Comment: @oneofone Official Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html